# Dynamically modify CSS rule in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, safari

Accessing my stylesheet works for me as per this example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Using_dynamic_styling_information

```
document.styleSheets[1].cssRules[0].style.backgroundColor="blue";
```

This works perfectly on other browsers I tested, but not on Safari. Even the page I linked won't work on Safari (it works on iPhone but not on a Mac) - the background color remains red.

Is there an alternative which works for Safari?

By the way, Mozilla's documentation has some contradictions - this page says that the style property is readonly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleRule

But they modify it in an example, also people do it in examples all over the web. So I am not sure the problem is in Safari. Either way, I need a working way to change the CSS rules dynamically.

Comment: I'm not really fond of directly modifying a style sheet. You could create various classes and toggle the association to the html element with more success. Style sheets are not meant to be dynamic.

Comment: I am already doing that, but my application has a dynamic number of tabs since some of the content might not be available for the user. If a tab is missing, I need to change the whole class which I add on tab select in order to resize the picture. Also some CSS classes have :hover and :active and I need to resize them too.

Comment: I'm looking at your [linked example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Using_dynamic_styling_information) right now in Safari on Mac.  All of the examples on the page are working fine for me.  Are you sure you haven't disabled JavaScript or something?

Comment: This is very surprising. I'm sure Javascript isn't disabled, the command fails even if I type it at the console. My Safari is the latest version, with OS X 10.10 Yosemite. Tomorrow I'll run the program on someone else's Mac and see what happens.

Comment: You need to flag me or I won't get your reply.  I'm using a Mac Pro running Yosemite 10.10.3 and Safari 8.0.6

Comment: @Sparky: Just tried it with someone else's Mac, completely independently used from mine. The text was blue (working) when we open the page and red (not working) when we refresh it. So no, it doesn't work reliably.

Comment: @VelizarHristov -- make enough color variations to accommodate the tabs...then just use logic to make it loop back around to color[0] if the number of tabs exceeds color.length. I use Compass/Sass to handle situations like this and just have it generate the classes based on an array of hex colors...then you don't modify your css at run-time. Just make yourself a rule and don't do that.